# How to say "for one's own sake"

Tags: idioms

Например: "He should listen to his mother, *for his own sake*".

Я думал, что-to похоже: "Он должен выслушивать свою мать, чтобы спасать себя.", но это казалось слишком буквально, так как на английском течение должен быть более метафоричный.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В данном контексте я бы перевел

> ...for his own sake

как

> ...для своего же блага

А все вместе так:

> Он должен слушать свою мать ради своего же блага.

Или

> Он должен слушаться мать ради своего же блага.

Comment: Да, кажется гораздо правильно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В 90% случаев, как мне кажется, вариант, предложенный Дмитрием, оптимален. Я бы только хотел дополнить, что в разговорной речи часто говорят просто что-то вроде:

> Он должен слушать свою мать себя же ради.

или

> Себя же ради, ему бы слушать свою мать.

То есть слово `блага` пропускают.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое. Конечно, есть значительный вариантов между разговорной и формальной, и я благодарен, чтобы получить разницу.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно говорят:

> для/ради собственного/своего (же) блага или ради самого себя/ради себя самого.

При этом слово *самого* изменяется по родам(ради самой себя/ради себя самой).Можно еще короче-*ради себя*